# How to get the time value from DateTime datatype

Tags: c#

I have DateTime variable, and I need to get ONLY the time value from that variable.

How can I do that in C#?

Thanks,

Comment: 5 seconds with intellisense would answer this one...

Comment: And yet, answers to such questions always garner a lot of votes compared to those which require complex code solutions. Sometimes I wonder!

Comment: @Cerebrus: i think these question always garner a lot of votes, because a lot of users go to the question to answer because its too easy, then they found that exactly the same what they going to answer is already written, so the give it a vote up !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this....

```
someDateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 9):

Check `TimeOfDay` property of the `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 9):

`dt.TimeOfDay` will return the time as a `TimeSpan` object.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can also use the string formatting for getting the output nicely

```
string.Format("{0: hh:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need string representation of time you can use:

```
dt.ToShortTimeString()
dt.ToLongTimeString()
```